# String manipulation using strtok/ sscanf in C

Tags: c, strtok, scanf

I'm trying to separate the following string into three separate variables, i.e., a, b and c.:

```
"   mov/1/1/1,0 STR{7}, r7"
```

each need to hold a different segment of the string, e.g:

```
a = "mov/1/1/1,0"
b = "STR{7}"
c = "r7"
```

There may be a space or also a tab between each command; this what makes this code part trickier.

I tried to use `strtok`, for the string manipulation, but it didn't work out.

```
char command[50] = "    mov/1/1/1,0 STR{7}, r7";
char a[10], b[10], c[10];
char * ptr = strtok(command, "\t");
strcpy(a, ptr);
ptr = strtok(NULL, "\t");
strcpy(b, ptr);
ptr = strtok(NULL, ", ");
strcpy(c, ptr);
```

but this gets things really messy as the variables `a, b` and `c` get to hold more values than they should, which leads the program to crash.

Input may vary from:

```
"   mov/1/1/1,0 STR{7}, r7"
"jsr /0,0            PRTSTR"
"mov/1/1/0,0         STRADD{5}, LASTCHAR {r3} "
```

in which the values of a,b and c change to different part of the given string.

I was told it is safer to use sscanf for that kind of manners than strtok, but I'm not sure why and how it could assist me.

I would be more than glad to hear your opinion!

Comment: `mov/1/1/0,0` and `LASTCHAR {r3}` It would be longer than nine characters(`a[10]`,`c[10]`).

Comment: You say you want things separated by "a space or also a tab", but then you use `strtok` with only `"\t"` as the separator.  Perhaps you just want `" \t"` (spaces or tabs, like you say), though that will take any sequence of one or more spaces or tabs as a delimeter.  If you want two spaces to mean an 'empty' field, that won't work.

Comment: Your sample string `"jsr /0,0  PRTSTR"` throws a spanner in the works; it has a significant comma in the second field, whereas in the other two example strings, the comma in the second field is not significant.  If you need to remove trailing commas, you can do that after the space-based splitting.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick :

`sscanf(command, "%s,%s,%s", &a, &b, &c)`

From scanf manpage, `%s` eats whitespaces, be them spaces or tabs :

> s : Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer
>   must be a pointer to character array that is long enough to hold the
>   input sequence and the terminating null byte ('\0'),  which is  added 
>   automatically. The  input string stops at white space or at the
>   maximum field width, whichever occurs first.

Comment: This includes the trailing comma in the second string, which doesn't appear to be the OP's desired goal. Perhaps update your format spec to account for that.

Comment: Thanks, it kind of did the trick of certain cases, but in others, there may be tabs or spaces between each phrase which causes the sscanf not to read it properly. also, in the second string it leaves a comma at the end of the string, which shouldn't be part of it

Comment: Guys, the whitespaces between each string may change in different commands, it varies from single space to tabs this really make things harder.. p.s I just added few examples of the given values

Comment: @RonNuni If you're looking for a universal sscanf format specifier for all those formats you may have your work cut out for you. Regarding what *this* specific answer was trying to convey, try `"%s %[^,], %s"`, but I'd seriously consider a most robust approach.

Comment: @WhozCraig, thanks that does actually work for most of the cases, but the fact that the amount of whitespaces vary each run is what giving me a hard time, because the variables a, b and c do not initialize properly

Comment: @RonNuni Then go for something that gets you close on all three variables, and muck with each afterward. With all of your potential formats, I don't think a silver bullet exists. You may have to parse this out the hard way (sometimes, it just has to be done).

Comment: @WhozCraig, yup, you were right about I did have to create my own functions and to handle most of the 'events' by my self. Just a small question, how can I take a small piece of the string and to initialize a variable with it. e.g., from the string: "mov/1/1/0,0         STRADD{5}, LASTCHAR {r3} "... how can I initialize variable "a" with mov? (run untill I reach "/")?

Answer (score 0):

As you might be knowing that you can use `sscanf()` the same way as `scanf()`, the difference is sscanf scans from string, while scanf from standard input.
In this problem you can specify scanf, with a set of characters to "always skip", as done in [this link](http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps012a/Fall98/faq/scanfQ.html).
Since you have different set of constraints for scanning all the three strings, you can specify, using `%*[^...]`, these constraints, before every `%s` inside sscanf().

Answer (score 0):

I have reservations about using `strtok()`, but this code using it seems to do what you need.  As I noted in a comment, the sample string `"jsr /0,0 PRTSTR"` throws a spanner in the works; it has a significant comma in the second field, whereas in the other two example strings, the comma in the second field is not significant. If you need to remove trailing commas, you can do that after the space-based splitting — as shown in this code.  The second loop tests the `zap_trailing_commas()` function to ensure that it behaves under degenerate cases, zapping trailing commas but not underflowing the start of the buffer or anything horrid.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void zap_trailing_commas(char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    while (len-- > 0 && str[len] == ',')
        str[len] = '\0';
}

static void splitter(char *command)
{
    char a[20], b[20], c[20];
    char *ptr = strtok(command, " \t");
    strcpy(a, ptr);
    zap_trailing_commas(a);
    ptr = strtok(NULL, " \t");
    strcpy(b, ptr);
    zap_trailing_commas(b);
    ptr = strtok(NULL, " \t");
    strcpy(c, ptr);
    zap_trailing_commas(c);
    printf("<<%s>> <<%s>> <<%s>>\n", a, b, c);
}

int main(void)
{
    char data[][50] =
    {
        "   mov/1/1/1,0 STR{7}, r7",
        "jsr /0,0            PRTSTR",
        "mov/1/1/0,0         STRADD{5}, LASTCHAR {r3} ",
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]); i++)
        splitter(data[i]);

    char commas[][10] = { "X,,,", "X,,", "X,", "X" };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(commas)/sizeof(commas[0]); i++)
    {
        printf("<<%s>> ", commas[i]);
        zap_trailing_commas(&commas[i][1]);
        printf("<<%s>>\n", commas[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
<<mov/1/1/1,0>> <<STR{7}>> <<r7>>
<<jsr>> <</0,0>> <<PRTSTR>>
<<mov/1/1/0,0>> <<STRADD{5}>> <<LASTCHAR>>
<<X,,,>> <<X>>
<<X,,>> <<X>>
<<X,>> <<X>>
<<X>> <<X>>
```

I also tested a variant with commas in place of the X's and that left the single comma alone.